# Filtering datatable at initialisation: filter row with empty column

Tags: datatables, filtering

I use Datatable and want to filter (not show) rows with empty column
I have a tsimple table with 2 rows :

- first row : fourth column is empty          **-> this line mut be filtered (hide)**
- second column : fourth colum contain a link **-> this line must be shown**

I try to use aoSearchCols option using a regex but the 2 lines are filtered
I don't understand what is doing bEscapeRegex but doesn't not impact result if I set true or even if I remove

I have tested my regex expression and it seems to works

moreover, reading different forums and Datatable docs sometimes it is searchCols and other times it is aosearchCol

```
"aoSearchCols": [ // filtre sur les lignes pour lesquelles la collone 'Actions' dispose d'un lien
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "sSearch": "^[A-Z]", "bEscapeRegex": false }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following `searchCols` option should work:

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  "searchCols": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    {
      "regex": true,
      "search": ".+"
    }
  ]
} );
```

This assumes your table has exactly 4 columns in it.

The `.+` regular expression ensures that the fourth column must contain some text (one or more characters).

(Using this approach means there is no way for the user to un-hide those initially hidden columns. I assume that is OK.)

---

I noticed that you are using the older-style Hungarian notation names for your options - for example, `aoSearchCols` instead of `searchCols`. If you are using DataTables 1.10+, I recommend you update to the newer camel-case names (as I use here).

Also, I was not able to find `bEscapeRegex` in the [list of old names](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10-convert). If that name does not exist, then perhaps that is also causing you a problem, in your example.

**Update:**

I found this reference [here](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.7#Common-upgrade-issues) regarding `bEscapeRegex`:

> `bEscapeRegex` has now been replaced by `bRegex`, which basically has the same meaning, but is the **boolean NOT** of `bEscapeRegex`. When `bRegex` is true, the filtering string is treated by DataTables as a regular expression, when it is false, the string is treated literally, rather than as a pattern. Any instance of `bEscapeRegex` **must be updated**. This was done to provide a more approachable filtering API as part of a wider tidy up.

This note was part of the upgrade to version 1.7 (very old!).